# How can I change the keyboard model in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, keyboard

In Ubuntu 11.10, in settings for Keyboard Layout:

I could change the keyboard model in earlier Ubuntu-versions. (104 keys, 106 keys and so on). How can i do this in Ubuntu 11.10? - the setting is gone from where it used to be (keyboard layouts).

Answer (score 1):

There is a `XKBMODEL` variable in `/etc/default/keyboard`. However I don't know why was it removed from settings and what are the possible options.